# undefined offset in laravel

Tags: checkbox, laravel-5

Here am getting offset while one of the checkbox gets unchecked,here is the checkbox list

```
<input type="checkbox" id="day_off_1" name="day_off[]" checked  value="1" class="switch-input day_off">
<input type="checkbox" id="day_off_2" name="day_off[]" checked  value="1" class="switch-input day_off">
<input type="checkbox" id="day_off_3" name="day_off[]" checked  value="1" class="switch-input day_off">
```

Here is my controller code

```
$off = (!empty(Input::get('day_off'))) ? Input::get('day_off') : 0;
```

i tried to use `isset` in place of `!empty` but not getting allowed to use that,here if checked i want the value `1` to be stored otherwise `0`

Comment: Any body have any idea

Comment: You have used array so you will get value in controller, in your case as all have same values you will not able to distinguish which checkbox selected, so change values as `1, 2, 3` and in controller print array you will get checked value in array only

Comment: To distinguish which checkbox is checked had already been done in my code now i want just to insert if checked the value 1 to be stored otherwise 0

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to have different values as you have array as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="day_off_1" name="day_off[]" checked  value="1" class="switch-input day_off">
<input type="checkbox" id="day_off_2" name="day_off[]" checked  value="2" class="switch-input day_off">
<input type="checkbox" id="day_off_3" name="day_off[]" checked  value="3" class="switch-input day_off">
```

Now in controller, you will get only checked value i.e if `day_off_3` checkbox is checked you will get `3` in your `day_off` array.

In controller, you can add code like below:

```
$dayOff = Input::get('day_off');
if(is_array($dayOff) && in_array(3, $dayOff)){
 //do something
}
```